# Projectile motion where gravity is a function of $y$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

I know what are the laws that describe the [projectile motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion), and in particular I need to compute the vertical displacement of the projectile at any time $t$:

$$ y = y_0 + v_0\sin(\theta)\,t - \frac{1}{2}gt^2 $$

But (I assume in my problem that) the gravity acceleration $g$ [is not a constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Estimating_g_from_the_law_of_universal_gravitation):

$$ g = \frac{Gm}{r^2} $$

Therefore, I can write the first equation as:

$$ y = y_0 + v_0\sin(\theta)\,t - \frac{K}{y^2}t^2 \quad , \quad K = \frac{Gm}{2} $$
$$ y^3 - (y_0 + v_0\sin(\theta)\,t) \cdot y^2 + Kt^2 = 0 $$

Now I always need to get the vertical displacement of the projectile at any time $t$, and I tried to solve the equation by means of the [cubic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) formula, but I get unfeasible values, so I think there must be some error.

I'm wondering where it is.

Comment: The equation you've used: $s = ut + \tfrac{1}{2}at^2$ is only true when the acceleration is constant, and will not describe the motion in this case.

Comment: @JohnRennie ok, then what is the equation that describes the motion in my case?

Comment: Related SO post http://stackoverflow.com/q/21983784/380384

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved using differential equations. If at any point the acceleration is a function of height such as

$$ a(y) = - \frac{G M}{(R+y)^2} $$

with initial conditions $t_0$, $y_0$ and $v_0$ the equations that govern the motion are

$$  a(y) = \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}t} = \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}y} \frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} = v \frac{{\rm d}v}{{\rm d}y}\Rightarrow \int \limits_{v_0}^v v {\rm d}v= \int \limits_{y_0}^y a(y)\,{\rm d}y$$

$$ \frac{1}{2} v^2 - \frac{1}{2} v_0^2 =-GM \frac{y-y_0}{(R+y_0)(R+y)} $$

(see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/41759/392)

Once you solve in terms of $v(y)= \sqrt{ v_0^2 + \frac{2 GM}{R+y} + \frac{2 GM}{R+y_0}}$ you can find the time by

$$ t-t_0 = \int \limits_{y_0}^{y} \frac{1}{v(y)}\,{\rm d}y $$ which is *not* an easy integral to solve.

Comment: But I don't need the time, I need the vertical displacement at time $t$. Since you have $v(y)$ how can I compute $y(t)$?

Comment: the last integral yields $t(y)$ which you need to invert to get $y(t)$.

Comment: I think the point is you cannot come up easily with an equation and it is far simpler and more powerful to create a simulation varying distance and speed with each time step.

Comment: I don't know how to invert $t(y)$ to get $y(t)$. I'd appreciate if you show me how to do. Anyway I get your point about the simulation.

Comment: **If** $t(y)=-\frac{1}{b} \ln \left( \frac{y}{A} \right)$ for example then $y(t)=A \exp \left(-b t\right)$ is the inverse. But in this case $t(y)$ isn't an invertible function I think.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you are taking your $y$ value to be from the ground, however the value of $g$ depends on the value of $r$, which is the radius of the earth from the center, not the distance from the ground. You should do something like $r = r_{earth} + y$

Comment: I don't think so, i tried as you said but I still get unfeasible values. The problem is the equation. The "original" one is a parabola, the one I get is something completely different. Please try to write the equation you are proposing in your answer; then try to replace constants in your equation in order to check if the results are feasible

Comment: The form of @ja72 's answer is what I was hinting at (he has chosen r = R + y in his answer).

Comment: You can't simply replace $y$ with $R + y$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Increment time $t = t + dt$
2. Increment coordinates. $x = x + v_x dt, y = y + v_y dt$
3. Recompute force $a(x,y)=F/m$
4. Increment speed $v_i=v_i + a_i dt$
5. Add here whatever gravity you want with any forces.
6. Close above in loop on any computer.
7. Do this every time teachers want you to solve yet another problem of projectiles and save your time.